# Associated prime of $M/Q$ where $Q$ is $\mathfrak{p}$-primary

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I need check if my statement is true and  proof check (for some reason I couldn't find this anywhere):

> Let $Q$ be a $\mathfrak{p}$-primary submodule of $A$-module $M$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$  is the only  associated ideal of $M/Q$.

Every  $a\in A$  for  which $a_{M/Q}$ is nilpotent are  in $\mathfrak{p}$ by definition. Let $\mathfrak{p'}$ be any associated prime of $M/Q$ which means there is $x+Q$ and $\forall a\in  $$\mathfrak{p'}$,  $ax \in Q$ so $a$ is not injective and must be nilpotent and $\mathfrak{p'}\subset \mathfrak{p}$ .

Conversely, let $a\in \mathfrak{p}$, and $\mathfrak{p'}$ associated prime of $M/Q$ which annihilates $x+Q$ $\Rightarrow$ $a^n\in\mathfrak{p'}$ so $a \in \mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{p'}$.

The problem is there doesn't have to exist any associated prime of $M/Q$, right?  So actually I proved: IF  there exists associated prime it is equal to  given prime $\mathfrak{p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem is true if $A$ is a *noetherian ring*.

Now it remains true for general rings if you use the *weakly associated prime ideals* and the corresponding notion of primary submodules.

All this is defined in *Bourbaki*, *Commutative algebra*, ch IV, *Associated prime ideals and primary decomposition*, §1, Ex.17 and §2, ex.12.